# In C++ books, array bound must be constant expression, but why the following code works?

Tags: c++, variable-length-array

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n=10;
    int a[n];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        a[i]=i+1;
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

worked fine in Xcode4 under Mac

as said in books, it should be wrong, why?

so confused~

Comment: To do this in a standard compliant way you'd use alloca()

Comment: `alloca()` is not standard C++ either. The standard method is in fact `std::vector<int> a(n)`

Comment: That it "works" doesn't mean it's not wrong :)
`char* ptr = "lol"; *ptr = 'a';` sometimes "works" too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that reminded me of how I learned not to modify const strings in a very very very painful way :)

Comment: For much more details also see [Does “int size = 10;” yield a constant expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21273829/1708801)

Answer (score 6):

This a a C99 feature called [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which some compilers also allow in C++. It's allocation on stack, just as it would be with `int a[10]`.

Answer (score 5):

That is C99 feature that allows VLA (variable length array).

Compile it with `g++ -pedantic`, I'm sure that wouldn't compile.

Comment: You might also need `-std=c++98` or `-ansi`.