# Unusual behaviour

Tags: c++, c

Why this code doesn't compile

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x=5;
int a[x];
int main()
{
     a[0]=5;
     printf("%d\n",a[0]);
     return 0;
}
```

When compiled with gcc filename.c -Wall -ansi -pedantic it produces a error

**error: variably modified ‘a’ at file scope**

However this code compiles although giving warnings but gives correct output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int x=5;
     int a[x];
     a[0]=5;
     printf("%d\n",a[0]);
     return 0;
}
```

**warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘a’ [-Wvla]**

However if i try to compile this using g++ filename.c -Wall -ansi -pedantic it produces **no warnings** and gives correct output too

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int x=5;
int a[x];
int main()
{
    a[0]=5;
    printf("%d\n",a[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc version 4.7.0

Please explain in detail what's happening ?

Comment: The `const` makes all the difference? The question is basically "why does incorrect code not compile, while correct code does?".

Comment: Study the exact reference of the language standards you are coding against. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_programming_language http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11 and pass `-Wall` to the GCC compiler

Comment: @LuchianGrigore So whats the answer ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++ books, array bound must be constant expression, but why the following code works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947661/in-c-books-array-bound-must-be-constant-expression-but-why-the-following-cod)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C(unlike C++) const declarations do not produce constant expressions, i.e. in C you can't use a const int object as array size in a non-VLA array declaration.

So,

```
const int max_foos = 10;
int foos[max_foos];
```

is valid in C++ but invalid in C. Equivalent C code will be:

```
#define MAX_FOOS 10
int foos[MAX_FOOS];
```

Note that:
***const in c doesn't mean constant. It means "read only".***

Note variable length arrays became a part of the C standard only in C99 prior to that the standard did not allow them though most compilers allowed them as a extension.

---

The first code snippet doesn't compile because the array subscript needs be a constant which it is not. Also, variable length arrays cannot be declared at global scope.

The second code snippet doesn't compile because variable length arrays were not part of standard prior to c99.

The third snippet compiles because const declarations produce constant expressions in C++ unlike C.

Answer (score 4):

In C only array objects with automatic storage duration can be variable length arrays. Object declared at file scope cannot have automatic storage duration.

In your second code example, c89/c90 does not have variable length arrays and you have to use a c99 compiler to use the feature. If you are using `gcc` you can select c99 with option `-std=c99`. Or you can use the last version of c: c11.

C++ does not have variable length arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Variable length arrays are supported only since C99 and they can't be global:

**C11, Array Declarators, 6.7.6.2:**

> If an identifier is declared as having a variably modified type, it
>   shall be an ordinary identifier (as defined in 6.2.3), have no
>   linkage, and have either block scope or function prototype scope. If
>   an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread
>   storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.

Comment: And the reason for downvote is?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and ?

Different generations of C and C++ have different rules for what you can use to size an array. In the first case, you are compiling to classic ANSI (C89/90).

C++ allows (constants) to be used as array sizes, as does C99. Note that the "original" C++ ANSI standard is newer than 1990, so it has a lot of the things added in the C99 standard.