# No error when defining an array of non-constexpr size

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C++ books, array bound must be constant expression, but why the following code works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947661/in-c-books-array-bound-must-be-constant-expression-but-why-the-following-cod)

I do this within main():

```
int i = 2; //not constant expression
int foo[i]; //no error?
```

This doesn't give me an error as it should according to my book. Why?

(i'm on clang 3.1)

Comment: Compiler extension for compatibility with C99 (VLA).

Comment: Note that it may become legal in C++14.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile it with strict warnings enabled.
`-pedantic` if you use gcc and it will give you an error.

Most compilers support variable length arrays(VLA) through a language extension. However the C++ language standard does not support VLA as a part of the language.

Comment: I'm on clang 3.1 - updated question. -pedantic gives me the warning "variable length arrays are c99 feature" though.

Comment: @user2015453: So it gives you a warning. A diagnostic is all that a compiler needs to provide you for using a non standard language extension. It does.

Comment: @user2015453 Try to add `-Werror`; I know this compiler flag from GCC but maybe Clang supports it, too. It makes compilation fail not only on errors but also on warnings (or turns warnings into errors, if you want to express it that way)

Answer (score 0):

Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99... for more detail have a look at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length

Comment: I'm on clang 3.1 - updated question

Comment: clang aims for gcc compatibility, so gcc doc is relevant.