# implicit constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Can C++11 compilers (and do they) notice that a function is a *constexpr* and treat them as such even if they are not declared to be *constexpr*?

I was demonstrating the use of *constexpr* to someone using the example straight from the Wikipedia:

```
int get_five() {return 5;}

int some_value[get_five() + 7]; // Create an array of 12 integers. Ill-formed C++
```

To my surprise the compiler was OK with it.  So, I further changed get_five( ) to take a few int parameters, multiply them and return the result while still not being explicitly declared to be *constexpr*.  The compiler was OK with that as well.  It seems that if the compiler can do this there isn't much point to having the restrictions that are required in order to explicitly declare something *constexpr*.

Comment: Maybe your compiler supports VLA as an extension. Did you consider that?

Comment: What compiler is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++ books, array bound must be constant expression, but why the following code works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947661/in-c-books-array-bound-must-be-constant-expression-but-why-the-following-cod)

Comment: I am using I am using g++ via MinGW-4.6.1 but also using the -std=c++0x and -pedantic switches.   I am looking into installing Clang at the moment, per answer by JC below.           @Bo - I am talking about the constexpr keyword, which is (supposed to be) required in the declaration of get_five( ) above.

Comment: @Arbalest - There is no implicit constexpr that I know of, but as Jerry Coffin answers below g++ (depending on exact options set) might allow some C99 features to be used in C++ as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a properly-functioning C++11 compiler, your code would be rejected.

Based on its being accepted, you're almost certainly using gcc (or something that closely emulates its bugs). gcc [depending somewhat on flags] can accept array sizes that aren't constant by any measure (e.g., depend on run-time input from the user) because they support an analog of C99 variable-length arrays in C++.

Comment: `g++` 4.6.3, 4.7.2 & 4.8 reject this. At least in the liveworkspace version

Comment: @icepack: Yes, I believe you can get it to reject code that uses VLA if you choose (but it accepts VLAs in C++ by default).

Comment: @icepack It doesn't reject it when it's in a function: [LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1QPoBc$2) - it does give a warning though!

Comment: That must be it.  I am using g++ via MinGW-4.6.1 but also using the -std=c++0x and -pedantic switches.

Answer (score 3):

GCC, as of GCC 12, supports the -fimplicit-constexpr command-line toggle which enables exactly that, for methods marked as inline.

- Changelog: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-12/changes.html
- Patch with some rationale and discussion: https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commitdiff;h=87c2080b

Comment: As interesting as this information is, enabling this flag does not appear to accept the OP's code (tested on [compiler-explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/MaEa3cKoP)). Either that or the `gcc-trunk` on compiler-explorer does not yet have the change, but accepts the flag.

Comment: It needs functions to be marked as inline:  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o81f1q3de ; I edited the answer to add this

Comment: While this is a welcome addition to the future of C++ development, I am sorry to say that it is not enough. If you do not mark originating data as constexpr on their declarations then the constexpr functions would not be used anyway. What GCC did is merely a measure to save typing effort, not retroactively optimize code! Allowing for greater developer-controlled optimization strategies would hugely benefit software modelling strategies!

Answer (score 2):

A compiler *can* detect whether or not a function could have been declared with `constexpr` even when they haven't, for *optimization* purposes (i.e. computing the result of a function at compile-time). Compilers did that prior to C++11.

But for use in places that requires constant expressions, such as template parameters of integral type, it is against the standard to allow calls to functions that are not declared with the `constexpr` keyword.

Comment: "__A compiler can detect whether or not a function could have been declared with constexpr__" Do you have any reference to back this up?

Comment: @cseder I find it hard to imagine that any modern compiler wouldn't do it. It is basic knowledge about how compilers work.

Comment: That's hardly evidence. And when you say "modern compilers" I guess you rule out the latest Visual C++ 2013 compiler, because it does not support automatic [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). A constexpr is only usable if the result returned from the constexpr function is the same every time and so does not need to include much knowledge about compiling.

Comment: I never said anything about memoization. There are other ways for compilers to constant expressions.

Comment: I just want to know what facts you have to back up your statement.

Comment: If you don't want to accept what is common knowledge, then so be it.

Comment: It's obviously not "common knowledge", when nobody has any fulfilling answers to it, you included. Over And Out.

Comment: Not many people pay attention to 7-months old questions. Read my answer again, and use google. I'm not going to do the work for you.

Comment: I'll just give you the last word in this discussion. It leads nowhere.

Comment: Well, maybe I'll just quote the only accepted answer while I'm at it: On a properly-functioning C++11 compiler, your code would be rejected.

Comment: I think you guys are confused. There is a misunderstanding between MERELY ALLOWING a compiler to change the specification into constexpr and FORCING it according to language rules. The latter allows user-defined functions to be tied into the compilation optimization strategy which is a key benefit.