# Purpose of constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

This is more of a philosophical question rather than practical code snippet, but perhaps C++ gurus can enlighten me (and apologies if it's been asked already).

I have been reading Item 15 in Meyers's "Effective Modern C++" book, as well as this thread: [implicit constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749825/implicit-constexpr) (plus a reasonable amount of googling). The item goes over usage of `constexpr` for expressions, namely that it defines functions that *can* return compile time values given compile time inputs.
Moreover, the StackOverflow thread I referred to shows that some compilers are perfectly capable of figuring out for themselves which function invocation results are known at compile time.

Hence the question: why was `constexpr` added to the standard as compared to defining when compilers should derive and allow static/compile-time values?

I realise it makes various compile-only (e.g. `std::array<T, constexpr>`) definitions less predictable, but on the other hand, as per Meyers's book, *constexpr is a part of the interface,..., if you remove it, you may cause arbitrarily large amounts of client code to stop compiling*. 
So, not only having explicit *constexpr* requires people to remember adding it, it also adds permanent semantics to the interface.

**Clarification**: This question is not about why `constexpr` should be used. I appreciate that having an ability to programatically derive compile-time values is very useful, and employed it myself on a number of occasions. It's a question on why it is mandatory in situations where compiler may deduce const-time behaviour on its own.

**Clarification no. 2**: Here is a code snippet showing that compilers do not deduce that automatically, I've used g++ in this case.

```
#include <array>

size_t test()
  {
  return 42;
  }

int main()
  {
  auto i = test();
  std::array<int, i> arrayTst;
  arrayTst[1] = 20;
  return arrayTst[1];
  }
```

`std::array` declaration fails to compile because I have not defined `test()` as `constexpr`, which is of course as per standard. If the standard were different, nothing would have prevented gcc from figuring out independently that `test()` always returns a constant expression.

This question does not ask "what the standard defines", but rather "why the standard is the way it is"?

Comment: Might be helpful: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#constexpr.

Comment: Without putting much though into my answer, magic values are bad, if your code automatically computes them from easy to understand parameters, then that's a big win in and of itself. For example I wrote some code to compute a crc32 at compile time with constexpr just today, and I think it's much more readable to have a function call to a constexpr that you can clearly follow, rather than a magic value computed who knows how. You also get the *guarantee* that things are computed at compile time, this actually saved my life once in a situation where static global initialization would not run.

Comment: @tux3: Sure, but there's no reason you couldn't have used a plain (non `constexpr` function) to do the same thing before.

Comment: `constexpr` is a guarantee of the interface: you can use this function (for certain inputs) where a constant expression is required, using **any** conforming compiler. The specification of `constexpr` defines the minimum capabilities that a conforming compiler must support when evaluating constant expressions.

Comment: @BillyONeal well, with a plain function you pointlessly lose some performance. If it's a trivial constant, it doesn't matter much, but when you have large arrays of them the gains can be significant.

Comment: @tux3 - Thanks for the answer, but I'm not saying that magic values should be used instead of `constexpr`. Rather at the language level, we could say that if a function answers certain criteria, it shall provide a compile-time value given compile-time input, such as your crc32 example.

Similarly on @dyp 's answer - we could theoretically say that a compiler is conforming if and only if it provides compile-time values in certain circumstances. Same circumstances where `constexpr` is allowed with C++11/14.

Comment: @tux: If it was a trivial constant the inliner could have inlined the calculation without constexpr. constexpr doesn't even require that the compiler compute the value at compile time -- only that if the value is needed at compile time, it is available.

Comment: @RomanK sorry, I wasn't really addressing your points. I think that the part where you get a guarantee of behavior and interface is crucial as others pointed out, without it you might silently turn a compile time computation into runtime. This would also introduce even more inconsistencies between compilers, but that isn't such a problem at this point.

Comment: @BillyONeal I don't think you can put simple constant folding on the same level as constexpr. Constexpr allows you to run much more complicated algorithms at compile time with an actual guarantee.

Comment: @RomanK Requiring a function that can be evaluated inside a constant expression to be declared as `constexpr` was in fact not part of the [original proposal](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1521.pdf). It appeared in Revision 2 of that paper; I'm still trying to figure out the rationale.

Comment: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28821610/1090079) for a detailed explanation of the usefulness of *constexpr*.

Comment: Thanks @dyp - this was pretty much the gist of my question.

@FilipRoséen-refp - that's a very good pointer. Maybe I should have revived that question instead of creating a new one. Your answer there is very reasonable, but just to play devil's advocate - why not make `constexpr` optional? I.e. if I really want to impose a contract, I can, but I don't absolutely have to do it in obvious cases such as example above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before `constexpr` the compilers could sometimes figure out a compile time constant and use it. However, the programmer could never know when this would happen.

Afterwards, the programmer is immediately informed if an expression is not a compile time constant and he or she realizes the need to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Hypothetically speaking, why couldn't `constexpr` be optional? I.e., if I feel so inclined, I could add the keyword to get notified if the expression is not constant (as you described), but still get benefit of compile time evaluations if I omitted it (including template args etc.)

Comment: @RomanK: Do you have evidence that you don't get that already?

Comment: Yes, I added an example to the question. If compilers did it, that would be against the standard.