# Does c++ standard support non-const data member being as array bounds?

Tags: c++

See the following code:

```
class X {
    int a;
public:
    void foo() {
        char arr[a]; // a is not a constant variable, but g++ doesn't report error, why?
    }
};
```

I always thought that only constant expression can be used in array bounds, until today I met the strange code above. Both g++ and clang++ can compile it successfully. But I can't find any description in C++ standard for supporting it. Is it an extented content of compiler? And where can I find some description about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++ books, array bound must be constant expression, but why the following code works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947661/in-c-books-array-bound-must-be-constant-expression-but-why-the-following-cod)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, C++ standard doesn't support [VLA](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler is trying to use the non-standard [Variable-Length Arrays](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) feature.

Frankly I've found that it doesn't always even work properly. Not sure why that has been the case, but I've learned to avoid it.