# Error related to defining and initialization part of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, constexpr

Am presently reading a book named C Primer 5th edition by Barbara E. Moo, Josée Lajoie, and Stanley B. Lippman. While I was reading a topic called array I encountered a problem related to the defining and initialization part of the array, and also a statement which confused me.
The statement stated that,

> ***The dimension of an array must be known at the compile time hence the dimension must be a constant expression***

The code on the other hand was,

```
unsigned cnt = 42; // not a constant expression
constexpr unsigned sz = 42; // constant expression
// constexpr see § 2.4.4 (p. 66)
int arr[10]; // array of ten ints
int *parr[sz]; // array of 42 pointers to int
string bad[cnt]; // error: cnt is not a constant expression
string strs[get_size()]; // ok if get_size is constexpr, error otherwise
```

When I tried to run the code as,

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<string>
using std::string;

int main()
{
     unsigned cnt = 42;          // not a constant expression
     string bad[cnt];         // error: cnt is not a constant expression
     return 0;
}
```

The following code threw no errors and run succesfully, with the output as,

```
PS E:\C++> cd "e:\C++\" ; if ($?) { g++ rough1.cpp -o rough1 } ; if ($?) { .\rough1 }
```

Well my question is that,

> *Is the following statement and the code error in the book related to the previous versions of cpp? Please explain in detail if possible, both the statement and the code part.*

Comment: In Standard C++, the size of an array *must be* a **compile time constant**. If your compiler compiles the above code(2nd code snippet), you're using a compiler **extension**.

Comment: Some compilers provide an unfortunate (and non-conforming) extension that allows this code without telling you that it's an extension.

Comment: Side note: Use of `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` along with `#include<string>` suggests you don't know what `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` does and how one is supposed to use it. [Here is some recommended reading on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). My general rule of thumb when I see `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in code is to approach the code that follows as though it will be a mess that will be hard to learn from. I'm rarely disappointed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In C++ books, array bound must be constant expression, but why the following code works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947661/in-c-books-array-bound-must-be-constant-expression-but-why-the-following-cod)

Comment: Some reading on the why: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AnoopRana and Pete Becker , as of now am using Visual Studio Code with MinGW compiler. Could you please suggest how to improve these kind of errors, or which compiler would be appropriate for the usage?

Comment: @Reborn Just make the habit of compiling your program with different compilers. Some of the most commonly used compilers include: **gcc** and **clang**. Another suggestion would be to **enable all warnings** when compiling your program. You're welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure how you specify it in VS Code, but you want to add `-pedantic` to the command line. I'd also add `-Wall` and `-Wextra`, and since the more you optimize code the closer the compiler looks at the code and may find more things to warn about, adding `-O3` to get a highly optimized build sometimes shakes even more warnings loose.